# Moving Box only with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a id=box inside html, having trouble using javascript to move the box with my arrow keys on the keyboard but as the code only goes down. Not up left or right. Not sure how my code is not working.

```
let boxTop = 200;
let boxLeft = 200;

document.getElementById("box").style.top = boxTop + "px";

document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

function logKey(ArrowUp) {
  box.style.top = (parseInt(box.style.top) - 10) + px';    
}

function logKey(ArrowRight) {
  box.style.left = (parseInt(box.style.left) + 10) + 'px';  
}

function logKey(ArrowLeft) {
  box.style.left = (parseInt(box.style.left) - 10) + 'px';    
}

function logKey(ArrowDown) {
  box.style.top = (parseInt(box.style.top) + 10) + 'px';    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried pressing any other key, for example 'A' and noticing what happens? You are calling the logKey function on any keypress, see for example the Mozilla Development Network documentation [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Eventsfor a list of possible events which outlines what the keydown event does There seems to be some misunderstanding of what is happening in the given code and I will post an answer with some of the things to look out for.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following code:

```
let boxTop = 200;
let boxLeft = 200;

document.getElementById("box").style.top = boxTop + "px";
document.getElementById("box").style.left = boxLeft + "px";
document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

function logKey(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode){
                        
         case 37:
             box.style.left = (parseInt(box.style.left) - 10) + 'px';
             break;
         case 38:
             box.style.top = (parseInt(box.style.top) - 10) + 'px';
             break;
         case 39:
             box.style.left = (parseInt(box.style.left) + 10)+'px';
             break;
         case 40:
             box.style.top = (parseInt(box.style.top) + 10) + 'px';
             break;
    }
}
```

the problem is, your functions `logkeys` always read the last one function and every key you press, it will just go down.

you can try it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJ2MNN4LBBYE)

Answer (score 0):

The question asks why the box only moves down when the user presses an arrow key.

A good start is to go through each line of your code and clarify exactly what it is doing versus what you'd like it to do. I'll put some things to consider in comments below so you can edit your code and then see if there is more to be done to make it fully work.

```
    let boxTop = 200;
    let boxLeft = 200;// where is boxLeft used?
    
    document.getElementById("box").style.top = boxTop + "px";
```

positions the box - depends on the position: styling of the box as whether this is relative to the current flow or the device screen (fixed) but you probably don't need to consider that at this stage.

```
            document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);
```

this binds the event keydown to a function logKey

BUT how does the system know which of the logKey functions to go to? There are 4 such functions here, JavaScript will probably go to the first one it finds. Did you see an error in your console log? You cannot have more than one function with the same name - in the same scope.

```
 function logKey(ArrowUp) {
ArrowUp will take on the value of whatever is passed to a function on an event. What is passed? And where in the function did you use this value?             

box.style.top = (parseInt(box.style.top) - 10) + px';
There is a typo here - a missing ' before the px. This function is therefore probably undefined - but there are 3 more so you may not have noticed as the system could pick up the next one. 

The next function is probably the one the system used when a key was pressed as the first instance was not valid. 
            function logKey(ArrowRight) {
              box.style.left = (parseInt(box.style.left) + 10) + 'px';  
            }
```

The following functions are never used as they have the same name as the one above

```
            function logKey(ArrowLeft) {
              box.style.left = (parseInt(box.style.left) - 10) + 'px';    
            }
            
            function logKey(ArrowDown) {
              box.style.top = (parseInt(box.style.top) + 10) + 'px';    
            }
```

Basically, when a key is pressed you need to look at the value of that key and see whether it's one of the arrows - i.e. test it against the values of the arrow keys (which you will have to find out and put into your code) using if statements or switch for example. If it is and arrow key do the repositioning of the box accordingly. If it isn't an arrow key then you just ignore it.

A really good way to debug is to use the dev tools in your browser (right click if on Windows for example) and look both at the console log to see errors and at the elements to see what code is there and if any is highlighted as having an error. You can also add

```
console.log(x);
```

statements in your code so at run time you can see what actual value something has. For example, put a `console.log(ArrowUp);` in your logKey function and see what it gives you.